# Почему автор использовал запятую и тире как единый знак?

Tags: запятые, тире, авторская-пунктуация

**Сарматов был по-настоящему страстным коллекционером, — именно коллекционером, собирателем, а не временным хранителем сокровищ, на чём он так настаивал.**

Какая здесь грамматика? Если это авторский знак, то какой смысл он выражает и как влияет на интонацию? Почему автор не использовал просто одно тире?

Comment: Извините, наверно, стоит поменять метки на _пунктуация_ , _запятая-тире_? Метка **и** все-таки  предназначена для союза (здесь его нет).

Comment: Я убрал метку *и* и добавил *авторская пунктуация*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что такую пунктуацию (запятая + тире) можно объяснить вот этим правилом:

Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное, усиливающее, дополняющее или развивающее главное предложение) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения.

*Я знала очень хорошо, что это был муж мой, не какой-нибудь новый, неизвестный человек, а хороший человек, – муж мой, которого я знала, как самоё себя* (Л. Толстой).
[Пунктуация. Тире. § 175](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

Без этого "нажима", усиления, можно даже сказать, акцента предложение имеет обычный "констатационный" вид с однородными членами.
Возможно даже, что здесь "напрашивается" вставка:
Сарматов был по-настоящему страстным коллекционером — именно коллекционером, собирателем, — а не временным хранителем сокровищ, на чём он так настаивал.
Но в таком виде предложение выглядит раздробленным, чего автор хотел избежать.

Comment: Может Вы и правы, но подход явно творческий, автор следует "не букве, а духу закона", обо запятая стоит не совсем точно "перед словом, которое повторяется".

Comment: Да, спасибо, я тоже думаю, что единый знак связан с темой повтора, возвращению к уже сказанному и более полному его раскрытию. Здесь и пауза должна быть более выразительной, не такой, как при обычной присоединительной конструкции

Comment: Я не филолог, поэтому мне не всегда удается на должном уровне оперировать терминами. Чаще всего я "прислушиваюсь" к самой себе и озвучиваю собственное восприятие - обычными словами. Наверно, профессионалы улыбаются, читая мои экзерциции.